# Insert into Table with some requirements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've some problem in mapping table in SQL server. The actual code is complicated, so I just make a simple example. Let's say I have 5 tables in the DB. Table A, table B, table C, table D, and Converted Table. View the image below for further detail.
[image: tables]
[image: mapping]

**Question is:** how to insert the record to new table in a simple way?
All I can imagine is insert ida,idb,idc,and idd in the new table by join table A, table B, table C, and table D.

Sorry if my question is really trivial. Hope you can guide me.

**Edit**
In case someone want to see the code. Here the code I've made so far.

```
use [db-sbr]
go
create procedure fillJumlahUnitInit
as
  declare
      @tahun char(4)
      ,@entry integer
      ,@exit integer
      ,@jumlahunit0 integer
      ,@jumlahunit1 integer
      ,@beroperasi integer

  set @tahun=year(GETDATE())-1

  declare @tahun1 char(4)
  set @tahun1=year(getdate())-2

  --pilih snapshot yang mau dipakai.
  declare @snapshotini varchar(max)
  set @snapshotini= (select name from sbr.dbo.snapshot_list where year(created_date) = @tahun and type='tahunan')

  declare @snapshot_y1 varchar(max)
  set @snapshot_y1= (select name from sbr.dbo.snapshot_list where year(created_date) = @tahun1 and type='tahunan')

  DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);

  declare
      @tabel1  nvarchar(max)='['+@snapshotini+'].dbo.commonthesis_en'
      ,@tabel2 nvarchar(max)='['+@snapshot_y1+'].dbo.commonthesis_en'

  --jumlah birth = count (id) yang tahun berdiri sama dengan tahun snapshot
  set @SQLString = 
    N'select @entry = COUNT(DISTINCT identerprise)
    FROM  '+@tabel1+N'
    where tahunberdiri = '+@tahun

  EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SQLString,N'@entry int out', @entry out;

  --jumlah death= count (id) yang thn kmrn aktif join tahun ini tutup on idA=idB
  set @SQLString=
      N'select @exit = COUNT(DISTINCT y.identerprise)
      FROM  '+ @tabel1+N' as y
      INNER JOIN '+ @tabel2+N' as y1
            ON y1.identerprise= y.identerprise
      where y.statusperusahaan=1 and y1.statusperusahaan=4';

  EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SQLString,N'@exit int out', @exit out;

  --jumlah awal tahun=jumlah akhir tahun kemarin
  --init
  set @SQLString = 
      N'Select @jumlahunit0= count (distinct identerprise)
      from '+@tabel2+N' where statusperusahaan=1 or statusperusahaan=2
      or statusperusahaan=3  or statusperusahaan=5)';

  EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SQLString,N'@jumlahunit0 int out', @jumlahunit0 out;

  --tahun berikutnya
  /*
    set @SQLString=N'Select @jumlahunit0= jumlahunit1
    from SBR.dbo.jumlah_unit where tahun='+@tahun1
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString,N'@jumlahunit0 int out', @jumlahunit0 out;
  */

  --jumlah akhir tahun = count yang blm berproduksi/tutup sementara       
  set @SQLString = 
      N'Select @jumlahunit1= count (distinct identerprise)
      from '+@tabel1+N' where statusperusahaan=2
      or statusperusahaan=3  or statusperusahaan=5)';

  EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SQLString,N'@jumlahunit1 int out', @jumlahunit1 out;
```

also I tried:

```
use sbr
insert into note (kddesa,kdkec,kdkab,kdprop,kdkategori,kdkbli,statusperusahaan,unitstatistik,institusi)
select distinct a.kddesa,
  a.kdkec,
  a.kdkab,
  a.kdprop,
  a.kdkategori,
  a.kdkbli,
  a.statusperusahaan,
  a.unitstatistik,
  a.institusi
from [db-sbr].dbo.commonthesis_en as a
JOIN [db-sbr].dbo.m_institusi as b on b.kdinstitusi=a.institusi
JOIN [db-sbr].dbo.m_unitstatistik as c on c.kdsu=a.unitstatistik
JOIN [db-sbr].dbo.m_kondisi as d on d.kdkondisi=a.statusperusahaan
JOIN [db-sbr].dbo.m_kbli as e on e.kdkbli =a.kdkbli
JOIN [db-sbr].dbo.m_kategori as f on f.kdkategori=a.kdkategori
JOIN [db-sbr].dbo.m_propinsi as g on g.kdprop=a.kdprop
JOIN [db-sbr].dbo.m_kabupaten as h on h.kdprop=a.kdprop and h.kdkab=a.kdkab
JOIN [db-sbr].dbo.m_kecamatan as i on i.kdprop=a.kdprop and i.kdkab=a.kdkab and i.kdkec=a.kdkec
JOIN [db-sbr].dbo.m_desa as j on j.kdprop=a.kdprop and j.kdkab=a.kdkab and j.kdkec=a.kdkec and j.kddesa=a.kddesa
```

Note: `note` table is the new table, `commonthesis_en` table is converted table, other tables are something like table a,b,c,d. `@entry, @exit, @jumlahunit0, @jumlahunit1` are variables from count. but still total count. (I want to count it by `institusi`, `unitstatistik`, etc. or in the example, by `ida,idb,idc,idd`.)

Comment: You wish users here to make the effort to solve your problem, but you decline to make the effort to type your work into the question where it is both readable, and copyable. I think not.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, I'm not decline. I just want user can understand the problem in the simplest way. If you, want the code, I can attach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use GROUP BY with select from `Converted Table`?

```
INSERT INTO [New Table]
SELECT  ida,
        idb,
        idc,
        idd,
        COUNT(unitid)
FROM [Converted Table]
GROUP BY ida, idb, idc, idd
```

Comment: ah.. may be I could use that. I'll accept this as an answer if its working.

Comment: Maybe it is even better if you create a view based on the select query.

Comment: So, have you checked?

Comment: ,I've try and It works like what I wanted. would you go to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553269/muliple-count-functions-with-conditions-in-sql-server) too?